# Where to find Office 2007/2010/2013 Open XML Schemas

Tags: xsd, ms-office, openxml

I am looking to pull together all of the XML schemas that Office 2007/2010/2013 documents abide by. I have found a number from the ISO/IEC 29500:2012 spec and ECMA-376 spec. I have also located a few on w3.org (e.g. xmldsig#). But I have been unable to find the majority of them (e.g. the schemas for `http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main`).

Searching on microsoft.com only yields pages like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd979954%28v=office.12%29.aspx) that seem to have this content. However, most of these schemas do `<xs:imports>`s  to files that I can't find.

Has anyone else had any luck finding these files?

Comment: Most of them are included in the ECMA-376 spec zips, including http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main.  Suggest you look there again.  Then there are the Office extension namespaces; Google for example [MS-DOCX].

Comment: 2007: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4463

Comment: 2003: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=101

Answer (score 11):

Note: I've left my original content below; feel free to remove it if that is the preferred way to post answers.

Initially I could not find a clear source for the namespace

http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main.

I found that http://purl.oclc.org/ooxml/spreadsheetml/main is used in the ISO/IEC 29500-1 and ECMA-376 documents.

When I was looking through the files in zip 'ECMA-376, Fourth Edition, Part 1 - Fundamentals And Markup Language Reference.zip' I noticed there are two sets of XML schema files:

OfficeOpenXML-XMLSchema-Strict (In Part 1)
OfficeOpenXML-XMLSchema-Transitional (In Part 4)

I found that the Strict schema uses the purl.oclc.org namespace while the transitional schema uses the schemas.openxmlformats.org.  Both sets contain the **sml.xsd** file (Defines SpreadsheetML) but with some differences.  It seems that the different version of MS Office support different verisons of the standards (found on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML).

**Original answer:**

---

It appears that the comment by JasonPlutext is correct.  I downloaded the file 'ECMA-376, Fourth Edition, Part 1 - Fundamentals And Markup Language Reference.zip' from the [ECMA site](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) which contains the file 'OfficeOpenXML-XMLSchema-Strict.zip' which then contains the file '**sml.xsd**'.

I searched for the namespace you're looking for and found this [website](http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/ooxml/ss.html) that appears to be an online version of the schema using the same namespace.  I checked a few elements and they all appear in the sml.xsd file.

What is odd is that that none of the files in the downloaded schemas contain the schemas.openxmlformats.org namespace they all contain namespaces like this one

http://purl.oclc.org/ooxml/spreadsheetml/main

you can navigate to this URL in a browser and it references the ISO standard ISO/IEC 29500-1.  I'd say they refer to the same thing but the purl version is less specific compared to the schemas.openxmlformats.org version.

Comment: I am unable to get any of the URL's mentioned in this thread to work. All of them are missing, redirects or other problems.

Comment: openxmlformats.org no longer exists

Comment: The ECMA-376 ZIP files are available at https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else is looking for this, here is where you will find a full list of the Office Open XML schema:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd979921(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: The link you've posted here is the same site that I referenced in my post. As I mentioned there, the schemas on this site do <xs:import>s of files that aren't included on this site. My original question was specifically about how to get the additional schemas which aren't available at the URL you provided here.

Comment: These are only for Excel. -- Not All of Office Open XML -- Note the missing schemas for Word and PowerPoint.